# Setting Ubuntu's capslock to backspace, and backspace to del?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I've managed to get capslock to backspace, now, for some time, with the following commands:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:backspace  
xset r 66
```

However, I tried something like `backspace:delete`, `backspace:del`, and even `22:119`, using `xev` to see what keys are actually being pressed, but to no avail. It's just a minor thing, but, does anybody know how I'd do this?

Thanks :)